# Facebook pixel integration between two websites, a main site and some pages in an iframe

Tags: facebook-pixel

We have a main website that we have a FB pixel installed within it, for the purpose of conversion tracking.

We have as well a booking process that takes place via a 3rd party solution in an iframe.   Not ideal but that is how it is.

We want to be able to track people that switch between the domains back and forth.

Is this possible and if so how?   I've found surprisingly little online to clarify this and FB's own dev formums seem to have very little on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can, by using the ip trace script or by linking it to the ip tracker website